# Добавление layout в view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Есть node.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Node"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/NodeAvatar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

и нужно его добавлять в View.

Comment: Ну добавляйте. Я разрешаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки наверняка же в гугле всё написано...

```
//куда добавлять
View view=//находим тут будущего родителя
//загружаем новый вью из xml
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View viewToAdd = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.node, view, false);
//добавляем 2-ой к 1-му
view.addView(viewToAdd);
```

Comment: А чем Вам Яндекс не угодил? Просматривая Ваши ответы, рекомендация исключительно гугла... который является заокеанским проектом, когда Яндекс - наш. ps. Ник тут не при чем ;)

Comment: @Чекист, Яндекс ищет ужасно. А кроме того, Google является настолько же заокеанским проектом, как и Android, интернет, и вообще компьютер. Так что смысла его не использовать я до абсурдности не вижу, тем более что он лучше по всем возможным показателям.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, я так пробовал, но когда я так делаю в AsynsTask, то он жаловаться начинает.

Comment: @Perkovec, а в каком методе асинк-такска вы это делаете? Т.к. к UI треду относятся только onPreExecute() и onPostExecuute(), то в doInBackground() у вас, конечно же, ничего не выйдет.

Comment: @Чекист Яндекс? а почему Спутник , что уж мелочится?

Comment: @Чекист, гугл, т.к.: раз вы на андроид пишете, значит у вас учётка там есть. Если есть учётка, то в хроме история хранится. История помогает лучше понимать ваши запросы. Плюс, мне думается, гугл больше проиндексировал программистских ресурсов. К тому же "иди в гугл", "погугли" etc уже слова нарицательные. А так-то да, в общем, я с вами согласен: проливу им. тов. Сталина - быть! =)